# is it possible to create installer for installed program?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, setup

as far as I know registry keys are needed for many programs.
I got some of my applications/games from my friends but now I need to reinstall my windows 7.
now I need that programs but can't get them again.I have them installed.
so is it possible to move a specific program registry to new win7 or make a installer from them?

Answer (score 2):

A program may not only need Registry entries to run, but also a lot of other things which are not necessarily in the installation directory:

- System DLLs, installed into C:\Windows\System32 or similar folder
- Frameworks like the .NET framework or the Visual Basic 6 runtime
- Other files, e.g. installed in the isolated storage or C:\Users\Public folder
- INI file settings
- Services which need to be activated, e.g. IIS
- Databases, e.g. Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition
- Special user accounts
- network settings, e.g. routes or virtual LAN adapters

Finding out what exactly a program needs is a task which cannot be completed by an ordinary user or even an ordinary administrator. You probably need reverse engineering skills. It may be easy for some programs (protable programs) but result in a neverending story for complex programs.

Even if you find out all required items, buidling a Setup which runs on Windows 7 can be yet another hard task.

So in my eyes - sorry - **there is no way to get the Setup back**.

If you really can't find it on the Internet anymore, here's my suggestion:

- clone your old Windows into a virtual machine. Make sue you have enough licenses.
- turn off network access to avoid security issues, because VMs seldomly have all updates
- uninstall all programs that you don't need to reduce disk size
- delete all data from the virtual machine that you don't need (MP3s, videos)
- defragment the hard disk (inside the VM)
- compact the hard disk (outside the VM), read instructions first
- Copy your data to the virtual machine, process it there and copy the result back

**The virtual machine approach should allow you to use the program in quite a safe way.**

Comment: did you see the win7 word in my question?

Comment: in my situation registry is only thing.other things are just easily installable.only registry is what I want to save.

Comment: @mpower (1) Yes, I saw Windows 7 in your question. I thought you're moving from an old XP machine to a new Windows 7 installation, sorry. Cloning may also work for Windows 7, but of course you might have a licensing issue then.

Comment: @mpower (2) How do you know? If you already tried and it works, that's fine. If you used e.g. Sickest's approach and it works for you, then create an Installer from the REG file you have. Try InnoSetup http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection

Comment: let me explain.I want to just install a new win on my pc.and I want to move what I can from this windows.also most of what I got from my friends is games.games usualy need `.net`,`directx`or... so only thing needed to move is registry things.

Comment: I don't think commercial games are that easy to distribute. They need Visual C++ runtimes etc., not just Registry keys. In addition, please consider using the games legally. I don't want to support moving (illegaly) copied games from one machine to another. For any free games it should be possible to find the installer.

Comment: so my only way is to copy folders of game's registries.